# Blob file in sqlalchemy python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

can anyone show me a clear process on how to save and retrieve blob file using sqlalchemy? I am having a hard time understanding the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BLOB is just a `bytes` object that we can store and retrieve like other column types. An example for table

```sql
create table employee (
    id int identity primary key, 
    lastname nvarchar(50), 
    firstname nvarchar(50), 
    photo varbinary(max));
```

would be

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

connection_url = "mssql+pyodbc://@localhost,49242/myDb?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)

new_hire = {'lastname': 'Thompson', 'firstname': 'Gord'}
with open('C:/Users/Gord/Pictures/HeadShot.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    new_hire['photo'] = f.read()

employee = sa.Table('employee', sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    # insert
    ins = employee.insert().values(new_hire)
    result = conn.execute(ins)
    new_id = result.inserted_primary_key[0]
    print(f"row saved with id = {new_id}")

    # retrieve
    sel = employee.select(employee.c.id == new_id)
    result = conn.execute(sel)
    row = result.fetchone()
    retrieved_photo = row['photo']

    # check
    print('ok' if retrieved_photo == new_hire['photo'] else 'FAIL')
```